# Is there a way to make Texstudio not to stop compilation upon missing figures?

Tags: graphics

Often the figure is not ready and in this case it is desirable that Texstudio continues to finish the compilation by ignoring the missing figures. I would say leaving a blank window there is a nicer treatment than stopping w/ error. Would you?

Comment: Are these figures inserted via `\includegraphics`?

Comment: this is a latex feature unrelated to which editor you use, you could use `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`

Comment: Or if you want to have a mixture of existing graphics and missing ones see [Check for a valid file before using \includegraphics](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/99070)

Comment: Yes I'm using \includegraphics.

I tried \usepackage[draft]{graphicx} but it gave me "Option clash for package graphicx." :(
The odd thing is some articles still continue to finish the compilation and show the contents despite the missing figures and the reported error, but the others dont...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`. Without editing the body of the document, all the images are black boxes, but if they have a defined absolute size (e.g. width=2cm,height=3cm) the format of text is well maintained. Useful for draft versions were the focus is the text distribution or when a faster compiling is needed. When you obtain the lost image all you need is remove the demo option.